# CMD/Powershell: Remove first four letters from folder name in path

Tags: powershell, cmd, directory

I have a folder which has many folder in it. ATM those folders have names such as "100_0103", "102_1212" and so on. I want to remove those "100_" and "102_" and so on, from all folders in the path.

I want to do this in CMD or Powershell.

Comment: anyone? I would really appreciate the helping hand in this question:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For PS, something like this should work.

```
dir | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | % { mv $_ -Destination ($_.Name.Substring(4)) }
```

Expanded

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_ -Destination ($_.Name.Substring(4)) }
```

Comment: This worked great! But after using this script the folder name is like so "DDMM", by this i mean day and month, but i want it to be "MMDD", so it would be easier to sort the folders. So the new question is how to change position of 2 pairs of 2 numbers, DDMM -> MMDD

Comment: @Marko - You should be able to build off of the example above. Just change the -Destination parameter (the bit within the parentheses). You can even use calls to Substring to reorder the characters of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set IN=100_0103

set OUT=%IN:~4%
echo Converted %IN%, got %OUT%
```

I get this output:

```
Converted 100_0103, got 0103
```

Which I believe is what you want. See [here](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) for more magic.

Comment: Hmm, I dont understand how will it change the folders name.

Comment: @Marko: it won't, it just shows how to extract the substring.